# Is there any way to record in excel if something is being printed before?

Tags: excel, vba

I am required to download and print loads of documents, which are then required by other departments. E.g. Invoice in pdf format.
Thereafter, I use excel to note my 'printing records' such as below:

[image]

Sometimes, I recorded them erroneously which have heavy implications! E.g. I recorded '1' even though I have not printed the document.

I wish to know if there is any way to automate this process? 
P.S I only have basic VBA knowledge so I apologize in advance for asking such a mediocre question!
I couldn't seem to find a solution on the net too.

Comment: **Two different topics** come to my head. `1.` You could want Excel to somehow detect and log in if a certain document was printed or `2.` You could automatize the entire procedure, where a VBA macro would ACTUALLY print the document, which would make "sure" it was printed, however keep in mind that sending a print command to the printer doesn't mean the document will be printed - perhaps there is no paper in the printer or the ink has just ended or there is a paper mismatch. Yeah. What I'm trying to say is that it would be awfully difficult to let VBA if a copy had actually been printed.

Comment: Yea I understand that this may not be feasible in VBA. Can it be done in another language though?